# Hiding and showing divs using click handler (JS) not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I have a click function that captures a clicked link and hides and un-hides some divs based one the following script:

```
$(".link").bind('click', function() {
  //link handler
  event.preventDefault();  //prevents url from changing
  // $(window).resize();  //testing something else
  var value = $(this).attr("href");  //grab hash link of li that was clicked and call it 'value'
  if ($(value).hasClass("active")) {
    return false  //if you click on the link that's already visible, don't do anything
  } else {
    $(value).removeClass("hidden").parent().find(".active").addClass("hidden").removeClass("active");  //unhide the div we want, find current active div and hide it
    $(value).addClass("active");  //classify the now visible div as active
  };
});
```

My .hidden class hides a div using display:none, and the .active class is my way of identifying the currently showing div.

It works perfectly in Chrome, but no dice in FireFox or Internet Explorer. Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT: Here's my css:

```
.hidden {
  display:none
```

}

.active doesn't have any rules, i just use it to identify the visible div.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j7df7/

Comment: show associated css and html markup please.  also try using `.on` instead of `.bind`.  what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Trim down your code to the essentials for testing and add complexity. Include all necessary code - no unnecessary code - and make a fiddle.

Comment: What event are you preventing? - I think you have to pass that into the function or it wont know? ???

Comment: preventDefault stops the hash link from going to the url. it messes up my view when i don't have that on

Comment: that works as well, but that doesn't seem to fix it not working in ff

Comment: @user3280523 Pretty sure that sheriffderek is right. `event` is undefined (or whatever you globally defined it as) when you call `event.preventDefault()` in the function. You are correct in your understanding of what `preventDefault` does but you need a reference to the event in order for it work properly, to do that you should pass a function that takes a parameter to jQuery like `function(event) { ... }` or the nastier approach use `arguments[0]`.

Comment: @Ardethian .on() "uses less memory and works for dynamically added elements." --- its just the new best way. .on()

Comment: @user3280523 - yeah - it's heart is in the right place --- but it's not correct -

Comment: Same thing with return false ---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working JSFiddle update that works with; Chrome, Internet Explorer and FireFox. I've steamlined your code, for example, instead of:

```
$(value).removeClass("hidden").parent().find(".active").addClass("hidden").removeClass("active")
```

There is now just:

```
 $(".active").attr('class', 'hidden');
```

I have also changed your

```
$(".link").on('click', function () {
```

To just (FireFox requires you put put an 'event' parameter in your code in order for it to work)

```
$(".link").click(function (event) {
```

Anyway, here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j7df7/3/

Here's a version where the divs have 2 classes, so you can keep one class for style and another for hiding: http://jsfiddle.net/j7df7/5/

Comment: you're brilliant, and this is almost perfect! maybe this is bad practice on my part, but the class attribute for the divs also contains other classes for styling and animations and whatnot and these are getting stripped (i believe) when the .hidden class is added. is there a way to do this while not touching the other classes?

Comment: @Xanco It really should be `$(".active").removeClass("active").addClass("hidden");` so that code doesn't have to change in the future if other classes (for styling) are added to the divs. I would say it's not a good idea to ever overwrite the class attribute like that.

Comment: Here you are, now our divs have 2 classes, one for styling and one for hiding: http://jsfiddle.net/j7df7/5/

Answer (score 1):

appears to be the event.preventDefault(); that is stopping execution in firefox. Comment that out and test again. Also, as sheriffderek mentioned, you probably should pass in an event so that your code knows what it is.

Comment: commenting it out worked. the problem is now it shifts the view down to my div which i don't want. is there a way to prevent that action?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you looking for?

```
$(".link").click(function () {
var value = $(this).attr("href"); //grab hash link of li that was clicked and call it 'value'

if(!$(value).hasClass('active'))
{
    $(value).addClass('active').removeClass('hidden');
    $(value).siblings('div').addClass('hidden').removeClass('active');
}


});
```

Comment: Are you asking if your answer is correct? Does that mean you didn't understand the question?

Comment: @izuriel. I understood question. I think that if someone looking for solution someone should give it one or other way.

Comment: My remark was to the "Is this what you're looking for?" which implies you don't really know what the person is asking and your post provides no real knowledge to the resolution of the problem from future readers who happen across this page with similar issues.

Comment: @izuriel. My goal was to provide quick solution to this problem and it doesn't mean that I didn't understood as you said. Also, I wanted to give short code which can be easily understood

Answer (score 0):

WHAT ABOUT THIS! I'm not sure if this will fit for you --- but I recently got turned onto data-* and it's awesome... try this out. It's pretty darn eloquent..... [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/J69gD/)

### HTML

```
<ul class='menu'>
    <li><a href='#' data-display-item='.one'>Link 01</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' data-display-item='.two'>Link 02</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' data-display-item='.three'>Link 03</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="SPA-block one active-page">
    Div 01 (Active to start)
</div>

<div class="SPA-block two">
    Div 02
</div>

<div class="SPA-block three">
    Div 03
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.SPA-block {
    display: none;
}

.active-page {
    display: block;
}
```

### jQuery

```
$('.menu a').on('click',function() {
    $('.SPA-block').removeClass('active-page'),
    $($(this).data('display-item')).addClass('active-page');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: It can be data-* anything --- so I probably should have name it something like data-display-page-content  or something. Just wanted to make it clear that you can use these data attributes for all sorts of awesome stuff - and the .data() jQuery helps ensure it's computability.

Comment: I would personally stick with `data-href` as a more canonical method of specifying an element to take action on when something was interacted with.

Comment: @izuriel - could you drop a little more detail in that wisdom if you have a moment? I'm looking it up - but it's not clicking. Should the OP really be using links at all, if they aren't actually links that are being progressively enhanced with AJAX or something? Crazy times.

Comment: Well, semantically if you're already using links just use their `href` attribute and prevent the default event action (which the OPed made a mistake by not taking the event in as a parameter); however, if you don't use links then I'd choose `data-href` as my data value for the simple reason that an `href` is meant to be reference to some other hypertext element/page so it would be following standard naming conventions within the HTML spec.